# how to write function to evaluate if String is only characters?

Tags: swift, string, set, character, characterview

I've seen other answers to this question, but I'm just trying to do it differently. Yet whatever I do I can't make my types *match*.

```
func ContainsOnlyAlphabets(_ word : String) -> Bool{
    let letters = CharacterSet.letters // Set<Character>

    let trimmed = word.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces)

    let characterViewArray = Array(trimmed.characters) // Array<characterView>
    let characterArray = characterViewArray.map{Character($0)} // Error: Can't create Chars
    let wordCharactersSet = Set(characterArray) // Set<Character>

    let intersection = wordCharactersSet.intersection(letters)

    return intersection.count == characterArray.count

}
```

I had to do all the Set,Char,String,Array conversions but still couldn't get it right :(.

> cannot invoke initializer for type 'Character' with an argument list
>   of type '((String.CharacterView._Element))'

Comment: What about `if trimmed.rangeOfCharacter(from: letters.inverted) == nil`  ?

Comment: Note that `CharacterSet` and `Set<Character>` are different types, so your approach computing `wordCharactersSet.intersection(letters)` cannot work.

Comment: one line solution `return word.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces).rangeOfCharacter(from: CharacterSet.letters.inverted) == nil`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code

```
let characterViewArray = Array(trimmed.characters)
```

already creates a `Array<Character>`, so you could simple skip the
next line and create a `Set<Character>` with

```
let wordCharactersSet = Set(characterViewArray)
```

But that does not really help, because `Set<Character>` and
`CharacterSet` are different types, so that

```
let intersection = wordCharactersSet.intersection(letters)
```

does not compile. Possible alternatives are

```
return trimmed.rangeOfCharacter(from: letters.inverted) == nil
```

or

```
return CharacterSet(charactersIn: trimmed).isSubset(of: letters)
```

If your intention is to allow both letters *and* whitespace characters
then it could look like this:

```
func containsOnlyLettersAndWhitespace(_ word : String) -> Bool{
    var allowedSet = CharacterSet.letters
    allowedSet.formUnion(CharacterSet.whitespaces)

    return word.rangeOfCharacter(from: allowedSet.inverted) == nil
    // Alternatively:
    return CharacterSet(charactersIn: word).isSubset(of: allowedSet.inverted)
}
```

Comment: So would it be correct to say if you want to work with `CharacterSet`s & `Set<Character>` then convert the `Set` to `CharacterSet` using `CharacterSet(charactersIn:_)`

Comment: @Honey: `CharacterSet(charactersIn:_)` takes a `String` as parameter, so you can pass the string directly, without creating a `Set<Character>`.

Comment: yes, sorry my mistake....only problem I have now is I can't do `.count` on a `CharacterSet`. Is there any workaround? My current solution is `let intersection = letters.intersection(CharacterSet(charactersIn:trimmed))  return intersection.count == characterViewArray.count` Only that the `.count` on `intersection` doesn't work because `CharacterSet`s don't have count...

Comment: @Honey: That's why I suggested `isSubset(of:)` or `rangeOfCharacter(from:)` – you don't need the array anymore. (`intersection` is a `CharacterSet` and `characterViewArray` an array, you cannot compare them)

Comment: @actually Right, seeing David Barry's solution I realized that it's stupid to compare two `set`s by their `count`. Comparing the `set`s themselves is enough.

Answer (score 1):

As MartinR noted, `CharacterSet` is not equivalent to `Set<Character>`

The closest I could get to your original solution was to create a `CharacterSet` from the trimmed string and apply some of your original algorithm to that:

```
func ContainsOnlyAlphabets(_ word : String) -> Bool{
    let letters = CharacterSet.letters

    let trimmed = word.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces)
    let wordCharacterSet = CharacterSet(charactersIn:trimmed)

    let intersection = wordCharacterSet.intersection(letters)

    return intersection == wordCharacterSet
}
```

Keeping it strictly in the realm of `CharacterSet` and operations on that, you could also use:

```
func ContainsOnlyAlphabets(_ word : String) -> Bool{
    return CharacterSet.letters.isSuperset(of:
        CharacterSet(charactersIn: word.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces))
    )
}
```

That said, I think I'd still go with Martin's solution:

```
func ContainsOnlyAlphabets(_ word : String) -> Bool{
    return word
        .trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces)
        .rangeOfCharacter(from: CharacterSet.letters.inverted) == nil
}
```

as being more intuitive.

Comment: You're solution returns false for `containsOnlyAlphabets("Thanks David")`. Something seems to be wrong for how it handles the white spaces

Comment: @Honey: `word.trimmingCharacters` (as in your question) removes only whitespace from both ends of the string, not *all* whitespace. If you want to allow arbitrary whitespace then the easiest solution would be to add that to the allowed character set.

Comment: @MartinR Thank you so much, followed what you said using`letters.insert(" ")` and it no longer returns false